# Monitor custom metrics in Spring Boot and Prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

I want to send some metrics, such as ResponseTime, RequestCount, etc. to Prometheus and then define a dashboard on Grafana. I know that I have to autowire `PrometheusMeterRegistry` in our class and use that as shown in the following:

```
@Autowired
private PrometheusMeterRegistry registry;

public void addSuccess(){
    registry.counter("RequestCountMetric", "success").increment()
}
```

Now, I don't know how to set up the Prometheus ip/port in our Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus uses a **pull/scrape** model meaning that instead of that the Spring Boot application sends metrics to a monitoring system, e.g over and UDP utilizing statsD, Prometheus will call an endpoint exposes by the application to pull the metrics.

Add `prometheus` to your exposed actuator endpoints in your `application.properties` in order to open up the endpoint `/actuator/prometheus`:

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus`

So, you actually need to configure your Prometheus instance where it can find the Spring Boot application.

Here is an example of the Prometheus config pointing to a local Spring Boot application:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  - job_name: 'my-application to scrape'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

Last step is to point your Grafana to your Prometheus which can easily be done in the Grafana UI and add the Prometheus datasource.